# No yarnrc.yml even after following directions

Tags: yarn-v2

This instruction:
`https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-to-yarn-2

```
says to run yarn install and it will create a .yarnrc.yml file. It does not. yarn 
install reports no errors and I can run yarn set version berry and I get:
Wed Jun 29 12:43:22 MDT 2022
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://repo.yarnpkg.com/3.2.1/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.1.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 327ms

I tried yarn set version 2 and then yarn install, but still no joy.
scottc in ~/Sites/vpermits.us on branch main > yarn set version 2    
Wed Jun 29 12:44:52 MDT 2022
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://repo.yarnpkg.com/2.4.3/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-2.4.3.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 391ms

My build fails with this error message:
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
   
-----> Creating runtime environment
   
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   USE_YARN_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Build failed
 !     The 'yarnrc.yml' file is not found
  It looks like the 'yarnrc.yml' file is missing from this project. Please
  make sure this file is checked into version control and made available to
  Heroku.
  To generate 'yarnrc.yml', make sure Yarn 2 is installed on your local
  machine and set the version in your project directory with:
   $ yarn set version berry
  Read more at the Yarn docs: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#per- 
 project-install
  
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed`

There is no yarnrc.yml (or .yarnrc.yml) in my directory.